# Problems when build Skia on linux

Tags: linux, android-ndk, java-native-interface, skia

Please help me about problems when i try build Skia by [this](http://sites.google.com/site/skiadocs/user-documentation) guide

It said that:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfreetype 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfontconfig 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGLU 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lX11
```

Thank's so much!

Answer (score 0):

/usr/bin/ld is the linker: it links the program you are trying to compile with existing libraries.  In your case, those libraries will be files named libfreetype.so, libfontconfig.so, and so on.

The problem in your case is probably those libraries don't exist on your system.  So you must install them.  The process for doing so varies depending on which version of Linux you are running.

On a Redhat, CentOS or Fedora based system, the process would be to do something like

```
yum -y install "*freetype*"
```

Look at the output of 'yum list' to find the exact name.  If you're on another type of Linux, perhaps someone else can help.

Comment: Thank's for your response! But how to find exact name of libs?

Comment: I typed: yum -y install libfontconfig-dev. But it can't.